# Translation in extension fails when not logged into backend

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I have an extbase extension that translates some variables on pages using this

```
if (is_array($row) && $row['sys_language_uid'] != $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content && $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_contentOL) {
     $row = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRecordOverlay($table, $row,$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content, $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_contentOL);
}
```

But there's a strange bug. It only works, when I'm logged into the backend. As soon as I log out, I can only see the default language.

Using Typo3 8.7

Any ideas what this could cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't figure out what the problem was, but found my own workaround for the problem. Here's the updated Code:

```
$table = 'tx_myExt';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE pid=".$pid;
        $query .= ' AND (sys_language_uid IN (-1,0) OR (sys_language_uid = ' .$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid. ' AND l10n_parent = 0))';
        $query .= " AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0";

        $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query($query);

        while($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            //localization
            // check for language overlay if:
            // * row is valid
            // * row language is different from currently needed language
            // * sys_language_contentOL is set


            if (is_array($row) && $row['sys_language_uid'] != $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content && $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_contentOL) {

                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE pid=".$pid;
                $query2 .= ' AND sys_language_uid = ' .$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content;
                $query2 .= ' AND l10n_parent = ' . $row['uid'];
                $query2 .= " AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0";

                $res2 = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query($query2);
                $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res2);

                //$row = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRecordOverlay($table, $row,$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content, $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_contentOL);
            }
}
```

So, instead of using `getRecordOverlay` I'm just repeating the query, accessing the translated record directly. I did read somewhere that this is bad practice, but hey, it works for now, that's all that matters ;)

Still, if someone finds a solution to the original problem, I'd be happy to see that.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have `config.sys_language_overlay = 0` defined globaly on your page object within your Typoscript Setup.

There is a [ticket](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/62921) entry in the Typo3 Forge that goes a bit deeper as to why this happens and provides some workarrounds if you need those.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did change config.sys_language_overlay to 1, but it's still not working. I tried some of the workarounds in that ticket, too, but nothing helped...